# Помогите написал код на TelegramBotAPI и вот начал писать кнопки и он не ставит на экран кнопки в чем проблема? Не шарю прост

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import os
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def start(bot):
    keyboard = [['RU', 'EN']]
    message = "Hey, I'm Bot! / Привет я бот
Please select a language to start. / Выбери язык для старта \
para comenzar."
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard,one_time_keyboard=True,resize_keyboard=True)
    update.message.reply_text(message, reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return SET_LANG
   
try: 
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
except Exception:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Кнопки создаются следующим образом:

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton("название кнопки")
markup.add(item1)
```